# how do i set a dynamic object in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to keep a value from a form by a js function
with `document.getElementById("form1")`
but in the form there are dynamic inputs amount1 , amount2 ect... (i dont know how many - its from database)
how do i reach form1.amount (p)
when p is the index of the amount ?
thanks

Comment: Are the input elements named with the `name` attribute or the `id` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve it like this:

```
 var frm = document.getElementById("form1");
 if (frm) {
     var valueA = frm["amount" + 1].value;
 }
```

A more complete example:

```
<html>
    <form id="f1">
        <input name="input1" value="text" type="text" />
    </form>

    <script>
        var f = document.getElementById("f1");
        if(f)
        {
            alert(f["input"+1]);
            alert(f["input"+1].value);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: if (sgn==1) f1.["amount"+p].value++; else if ( f1.["amount"+p].value>1 ) f1.["amount"+p].value--;   it didnt work !

Comment: @moby, this could fail for a number of reasons, e.g. if you don't define `p` properly, or if the `value` isn't numeric. Does it error or just not give the results you're expecting? Any chance you can post the code where you set up `p`, and details of what's going wrong? thanks

Comment: @moby: Not `f1.["amount"+p].value++`, but `f1["amount"+p].value++`. No dot is needed between `f1` and the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all input elements of a form by use of "getElementsByTagName". Like this:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form1");
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

That way the array "inputs" contains all input elements contained in your form.

Answer (score 0):

Ioannis is pretty much there. To get the value of the ith amount input, use:

```
var value = document.forms['form1'].elements['amount' + i].value;
```

A little more robustly:

```
function getIthAmount(i) {
  var o = document.forms['form1'];
  o = o && o.elements['amount' + i];

  if (o) {
    return o.value;
  }
}
```